What is the biblical concept/idea/meaning of Gods omniscience?
I have rewritten my question a few times because I had difficulties dealing with the definition of omniscience. Originally I wanted to know the difference between the concept of omniscience from a logical point of view with the view of the bible.
However, I noticed that defining omniscience from a logical or philosophical point of view, although interesting, is quite a bag of worms, that I should open with a different question though.
In this question, I am interested in the Biblical view/concept/meaning and limits of the omniscience of God. What can we actually conclude from the Bible on the nature of omniscience? In particular, I am most interested in the omniscience of God regarding the future.
So for a focused phrasing of the question:

What is the concept/idea/meaning of omniscience in the Bible?
Are there limits to this omniscience described in the Bible? If so which are they?

So a few Verses that I came across when researching omniscience in the Bible:
Hebrews 4:13

And no creature is hidden from his sight, but all are naked and exposed to the eyes of him to whom we must give account.

From Hebrews, I can conclude that God is seeing/is aware of every creature. The "exposed" part is a bit more abstract for me, but I think it points to the idea that humans cannot deceive God by lying or omitting information.
What I cannot conclude from Hebrews yet is a total omniscience, since it does not say anything about past/future or possibilities.
1 John 3:20

for whenever our heart condemns us, God is greater than our heart, and he knows everything.

So either omniscience in 1. John is focused on our heart here, meaning our inner thoughts, emotions, unconscious thoughts, and attitudes, and I would even go for other factors, like hormones. Or "everything" is referring to literally everything.
Isaiah 46:10

I make known the end from the beginning, from ancient times, what is still to come. I say, “My purpose will stand, and I will do all that I please.”

From Isaiah, I drew the conclusion that God knows everything that happened in the past but more importantly, what will happen in the future.
Matthew 10:29-30

Are not two sparrows sold for a penny?[9] And not one of them will fall to the ground apart from your Father.
30 But even the hairs of your head are all numbered.

The omniscience in Matthew seems to be similar to the one in Hebrews, basically saying that God knows everything that is going on physically.
Are there verses that I missed?

This site is about the exegesis of specific passages, whereas you're asking about bringing together many passages to develop a systematic theology of an attribute of God. That's off topic here. It would probably be best to ask this on Christianity.SE.

@telion, You could try creating a new question regarding the hermeneutical analysis and implications specifically of Matthew 10:29-30.

@Dieter Thank you for your advice. If BH.SE requires limiting it to 1 or 2 passages,  I think that I either have to ask 4 Questions to cover each verse I quoted or go to C.SE. I guess I stumbled upon the grey area between hermeneutics and theology because I thought it was possible to define omniscience using hermeneutics, but in doing so it's becoming theology. Quite easy to confuse the 2.

@telion, Yes, exactly. Also note that omniscience is an external, theological term not found in the Bible and that might easily be misunderstood or misapplied.
